# How to append 2 usestates in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 useStates I want to append both when I call `SubmitData`
`allValues`  has many data items `name, age, sex` etc..  I want to add   `domestic` also into all values.

```
const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setAllValues({ ...allValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};

const SubmitData = () => {
    console.log(domestic);
    
    const formData = { ...allValues };

    if (!domestic) {
      formData.domestic = domestic;
    }

    var customer = parseInt(id);

    if (!customer) {
      formData.customer = customer;
    }
}
```

When  `allValues` is empty and I only pass value of `domestic` I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'domestic')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Since you have been facing `undefined` problem, I update the logic a bit

```
const formData = {...allValues}
if (!domestic_voilence) {
   formData.domestic = domestic_voilence;
}
const customer = id ? parseInt(id) : null;
if (!customer) {
   formData.customer = customer;
}
//TODO: submit your form data instead
```

**ORIGINAL**

You can simply do this way

```
if(domestic !== null) {
   allValues.domestic = domestic
}
```

It will automatically populate your `domestic` data to `allValues`.

If you want to have `formData` as the main variable

```
const formData = {
   ...allValues,
}
if(domestic !== null) {
   formData.domestic = domestic
}
```

ES5 version

```
const formData = Object.assign({}, allValues);
if(domestic !== null) {
   formData.domestic = domestic
}
```

Comment: i ran into a bug while doing this

Comment: Could you show me how you set it up? I'm doubting that `formData` or `allValues` is undefined. You can make a further check like this `if(!allValues) { allValues = {} }`

Comment: i have updated the question  the problem occurs when i add only  domestic  and all other values are empty in  allValues

Comment: do u want any more code pls let me know

Comment: I added my updated answer, you can try it out, and please give me more feedback. Thank you :D @meon

Comment: You also have a problem with assigning value. `allValues.domestic = domestic;` it should be `allValues.domestic = domestic_voilence;`

Comment: i tryed ur answer now i am gettig following eroor TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Comment: in this  line  allValues = {};

Comment: hmmm it seems your `allValues` from state, I didn't catch it up earlier... You can try to assign a new variable `formData` which is NOT a state. That will help you to be able to update data @meon

Comment: @Niku i was able to add domestic form data but custumer is not able to add i updated question

Comment: `const custumer = id ? parseInt(id) : null;` you need to check `id` before calling `parseInt`. I modified my answer again :D

Comment: I fixed your typo as well, `custumer` should be `customer` @meon